# LiveCD shows options, but computer hangs after choosing one

Tags: system-installation, live-cd

Today, my computer stopped booting from its SSD, so I am now trying to boot from a USB LiveCD image.

I downloaded the 64b LiveCD image, put it on a 64Gb USB stick.

I can tell my BIOS to boot from the stick, and the LiveCD options come up.

But as soon as I choose an option from the menu, the screen goes black, and the computer hangs.

The computer is a generic 64bit Core-i5 with Asus H87M-PLUS motherboard. It was working fine earlier today.

The Ubuntu Server 64b ISO does the same: Comes up w menu, but hangs as soon as a choice is made.

I tried:

ubuntu-18.04.3-live-server-amd64.iso

xubuntu-18.04-desktop-amd64.iso

ubuntu-18.04.3-desktop-amd64.iso

**UPDATE**: I got it to work, I think the issue was with the partitioning of the USB stick. I prepared the USB stick on MacOS, and it looks like it forces a MacOS Partition on it, if you don't explicitly erase the DISK first, before flashing the ISO file.

Comment: Have you validated the ISO image as downloaded? or more so validated the install-media?  Possibly useful : https://tutorials.ubuntu.com/tutorial/tutorial-how-to-verify-ubuntu#0 and https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/CDIntegrityCheck   I would also run a memtest.